# Animating UIView origin only works after first try

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uiview

I have a UIView with some labels in it I built in my storyboard that I want to animate when a map annotation is clicked. I have everything working great except the animations are a bit off. The first time you click an annotation the frame position is not animated. But if I deselect and then reselect the annotation it animates fine from then on. I also animate the background color and that seems to be working fine on the first select so whatever it is is peculiar to the frame property, perhaps because it's no set up appropriately at load? Again I did all that in the storyboard so I don't know what I'm missing.

Code for my Labels/View (all built in my storyboard and using reference outlets to the proper IBOutlets). file.h:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *stationinfo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *stationname;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *stationsong;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *stationartist;
```

file.m:

```
@synthesize stationinfo;
@synthesize stationname;
@synthesize stationsong;
@synthesize stationartist;
```

Please find code for callbacks below:

```
- (void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    //NSLog(@"Selected ");
    self.stationname.text = ((userStation *)view.annotation).name;
    self.stationsong.text = ((userStation *)view.annotation).song;
    self.stationartist.text = ((userStation *)view.annotation).artist;
    [UIView
     animateWithDuration:0.25
     delay: 0.0
     options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
     animations:^ {
        CGRect anim = self.stationinfo.frame;
        anim.origin.y = 0.0;
        self.stationinfo.frame = anim;
        self.stationinfo.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
     completion:^(BOOL finished){
         NSLog(@"DONE!");
     }];
}

- (void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    //NSLog(@"Deselected");
    [UIView
     animateWithDuration:0.25
     delay: 0.0
     options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
     animations:^ {
         CGRect anim = self.stationinfo.frame;
         anim.origin.y = -100.0;
         self.stationinfo.frame = anim;
         self.stationinfo.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
     }
     completion:^(BOOL finished){
         NSLog(@"DONE!");
     }];
}
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: is `stationinfo.frame` being set or changed anywhere else in code?

Comment: is it just me, or is the line with all the `anim` juggling too wordy? You can just do `self.stationinfo.frame.origin.y = -100.0;` or something similar. But that shouldn't be the cause of the problem... Or maybe it is?

Comment: @Bash They are read only properties.

Comment: Just a guess but check that the annotations are in the intended location before you animate anything. Specifically check that you are setting the subviews frame in `layoutSubviews` if you are subclassing any uiviews.

Comment: @ohr really? It doesn't seem like it from the way he's setting the `frame.origin.y` to -100

Comment: @bash Nope. I just set it up in the storyboard.

Comment: @mkral I haven't done any subclassing for views.

Comment: @Bash For the animation to work it copies the view's existing frame, changes its y position, and then sets the frame to the copy. You can't change the existing frame and have animation work. I may try making the view programmattically instead of in the storyboard to see if that helps.

Comment: @ohr ok you're right. @Primus202 You should try setting the frame position upon launch (or in `viewDidLoad` or something) IN CODE. It *might* fix it... Won't lose much from trying I guess...

Comment: Yeah still no luck. Only decent work around I've found to work is setting the position in the complete function. It doesn't animate but at least it shows up on that first click that way.

Comment: Funny enough it works if I put an animation in the complete method as well! I've tried setting the frame and center before hand but neither helps. Are there other properties I may need to set that view animation is dependent on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** While the below worked before, I found that it was in fact no longer necessary! I can only imagine I inadvertently fixed the bug in adjusting my storyboard the other day when I was applying appropriate constraints and such to my layout to ensure it looked good on the new screen size.

The work around I found was to perform the animation again in the complete function. While inelegant it seems to work (since only the first animation call doesn't work this second one on complete does it again). Note this will cause a delay since the first try has to complete first. I'm guessing there's some property of frames that is initialized by the first animation which is required to animate the position.

```
[UIView
         animateWithDuration:0.25
         delay: 0.0
         options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
         animations:^ {
            CGRect anim = self.stationinfo.frame;
            anim.origin.y = 0.0;
            self.stationinfo.frame = anim;
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
            CGRect anim = self.stationinfo.frame;
            anim.origin.y = 0.0;
            self.stationinfo.frame = anim;
        }];
```

I guess alternatively one could fire a neutral animation before the main one as well to see if that has the same effect.